# gmap3 not showing map

Tags: jquery, jquery-gmap3

I'm using gmap3 to show a simple desaturated map of a single location. I've searched for a few hours to get it to work, but can't seem to find the problem.

non working page : http://omnibus.teunis.be/school/contact

based on : http://demo.owwwlab.com/wp-toranj/contact/

I'm getting the following errors in the console :

```
jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2
Uncaught TypeError: $gmap.gmap3(...).setMapTypeId is not a function
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (custom.js:398)
at Function.each (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
at a.fn.init.each (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (custom.js:358)
at j (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
at k (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
```

The page (scripts and css) itself is too complex for me to find the problem. Hoping to get someone to help me out on this.

I've tried using jquery 1.11.0 and 1.12.4 but the last one breaks my calendar page (based on fullcalendar.io)

Comment: Did you create new map id or using existing?

Comment: I just check URL , There is no error in the console.

Comment: Just create new map id for this url and use this. Hope this will resolve your problem

Comment: How do I create a new map id? I'm quite new at this map thing. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Check here:- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

Comment: Replace in your code with below line:- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=AIzaSyBjsuxap7KBMo4yPjQ_y9cdIPFjakDWoeg

Comment: AIzaSyBjsuxap7KBMo4yPjQ_y9cdIPFjakDWoeg This is your current key

Comment: The map seems to loadnow, but for some reason does not show on the page.

Comment: Fixed it! Changed some CSS and it shows the map!

Comment: please accept my answer and upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remember google map provides some security feature.

When we create key for map we can restrict the use for the given URL/Domain.

So when you copy code, please remember to change the map key also if map not works.

You can create map key at the below url:-

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

This will resole your problem.